# Linux :Web-based FTP browser?

Tags: linux, ftp

Is there any web-based FTP-browser that I can install on the Apache2 server which I am running my FTP service on? I am not talking about accessing through FTP protocol, but entirely through HTTP. Something like WebSVN for SVN access?

Reason for this is, that sometimes our clients cannot access our FTP service, because they are behind firewalls.

Comment: something like WebDAV (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Net2Ftp](http://www.net2ftp.com/) that I got after [doing this](http://www.google.com/search?q=web+ftp). Requires PHP.

I would also suggest yout to use a more secure way. For example, you could use [Mindterm applet](http://www.appgate.com/index/products/mindterm/) to transfer via SCP/SFTP

Comment: Don't forget [Monsta FTP](https:///www.monstaftp.com)!

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with web scripting languages like PHP or Perl, you could write a web app that does this. For an existing solution try http://oliver.sourceforge.net
It acts as a web-based front end to an FTP server.

Comment: Who voted this down and why?

Comment: Not really helpful, he was asking for software (so the question is unrelated). not 'what programming language I could use to achieve this' Another reason for -1 is mentioning PHP and Perl but omitting python.

Comment: I omitted Ruby. Do I get a downvote for that?

Comment: mimimi he didn't mention my favorite language, mimimi

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realise Python coders were so easily offended... and I am a Python coder myself, so...

Comment: Ok, sarcasm font was apparently needed. My point is that the answer is completely unhelpful, the OP could use **ANY** programming language in addition to the ones mentioned to achieve this, **if he wanted to do it by himself**

Comment: That's why I added the link to oliver - in case he DIDN'T want to do it himself.

Comment: @George: Don't worry about the downvote. Here, you get +1 from me!

Comment: ok, from me too :)

Comment: Someone downvoted again :(

Answer (score 2):

[eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/) is an Ajax based professionally looking web based file manager and ftp client that you can use.